# AutoHotKey key SEQUENCE, not just single-key hotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm not stupid... really.
How do you map a key SEQUENCE (ie: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> , <kbd>F</kbd>) in AutoHotKey.

I've got <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> down:

```
^q::
```

I've even got <kbd>F</kbd>:

```
f::
```

The examples in the help files even show how to do two keystrokes in a row:

```
Numpad0 & Numpad1::
```

But it just will not work with:

```
^q & f ::
```

Or any of these either:

```
LCtrl & q & f::
^q & ^f::
^q^f::
^qf::
```

How do I accomplish a Key SEQUENCE triggering something, when one of those keys is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?  I looked into using a HOTSTRING instead, but couldn't work out how to include the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> character, in that context!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Alright; The answer seems to be:

```
^q::
Input Key, L1
if Key=f
...some code here...
return
```

Comment: I've handled this in an effective but ugly way in the past. I like your approach better, and have combined it with the Progress command to make nice key-sequence menus, such as the one I use to launch browsers **[here](https://gist.github.com/ajkerrigan/a0e54dbdd5fb3dea5113)**. Thanks for a better way!

Comment: This messed up my ctrl key after a few tries, so for example I couldn't press ctrl-shift-escape anymore

Answer (score 5):

In case someone's looking for a similar thing, but actually want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and *only* if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held throughout (so, to some, this might seem like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), then here's how to do that:

```
$Ctrl::Send {Ctrl Down}
$Ctrl UP::
    ChordIsBroken := True
    Send {Ctrl Up}
    Return
^q::
    ChordIsBroken := False
    Input, OutputVar, L1 M
    If (!ChordIsBroken && Asc(OutputVar) = 6)
    {
        MsgBox "Hello, World!"
    }
    Else
    {
        SendInput %OutputVar%
    }
    Return
```

See https://superuser.com/a/725303/145431 for my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it like this:

```
q & f::
    if GetKeyState("Control") {
        ; Do something
        return
    }
    return
```

I think this is a bit more readable than using Input Key, L1 as in above.

Comment: The ampersand notation requires both keys to be held down at the **same** time. In caps, the OP specifies "sequence" so this answer won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This catches <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. If <kbd>Q</kbd> is held down at that moment, your code fires.

```
^f::
    If GetKeyState("q", "p") {
        MsgBox test
    } Else {
        Send ^f
    }
return
```

Comment: OP required a sequence of keys. This answer requires simultaneous key strokes.

Answer (score 0):

**AutoHotkey v1:**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33

^q:: ctrl_q := true ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
^q up:: ctrl_q := false

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (ctrl_q) ; If this variable has the value "true"

    ^a:: MsgBox, Ctrl + Q + A
    
    ^b:: MsgBox, Ctrl + Q + B

    ; ...
    
#If
```

**AutoHotkey v2**:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

^q:: ctrl_q := true ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
^q up:: ctrl_q := false

; The #HotIf  directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#HotIf (ctrl_q := true ) ; If this variable has the value "true"

    ^a:: MsgBox "Ctrl + Q + A"
    
    ^b:: MsgBox "Ctrl + Q + B"

    ; ...
    
#HotIf
```