# multi-letter shortcut in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to use multiple letters in a shortcut in Notepad++.  The UI does not seem to support this.  For example, I'd like to create the following shortcut:

```
ctrl + a + b
```

Comment: The UI doesn't expose this, and the [community docs](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/settings/shortcut-mapper) seem to indicate that shortcuts are limited to a single letter, so it seems unlikely that this is possible.

Comment: @Derek - can you add as answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: don't worry about it.  Demoncodemonkey's suggestion of Autohotkey might be worth your upvote / accept, though.  Give that a try and see if it works well for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible from within notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I can tell that Notepad++ seems to support multi-letter shortcuts by looking its [default shortcuts](http://losbyers.com/wordpress/2010/01/notepad-keyboard-shortcuts/); for example `Ctrl-Shft-S` is the shortcut of 'Save All'.

After digging the [Shortcut Mapper](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/settings/shortcut-mapper) of Notepad++ a little bit, I have concluded that you can create multi-letter shortcuts either `CTRL + SHIFT + KEY` format OR `ALT + SHIFT + KEY` format.

Check the image:

[image]

You can read [here](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/settings/shortcut-mapper) for further information about the 'Notepad++ Shorcut Mapper'

Comment: These are multi-key shortcuts, not multi-letter shortcuts.  I want to do something like CTRL+A+B

Comment: It doesn't look possible then (at least from Shortcut Mapper). Have you tried modifying shortcuts.xml file?

Comment: I'm not sure what I would modify.  The Ctrl/Alt/Shift attributes are all booleans and the Key attribute seems to take a character code

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use some external keyboard macro engine to trigger a certain command when a key sequence is pressed.

It looks like you can do it with [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096253/autohotkey-key-sequence-not-just-single-key-hotkey) for an example.

Comment: thanks!  I prefer not to install/manage another program, but this seems to be the only workaround