# AHK: Different hotkeys via sequences with repeating keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Ok my code has the following which works:

```
^m::Send M text{enter}
    Return

^s::Send S text{enter}
    Return

^t::Send T text{enter}
    Return
```

Now I want to be able to add something like the following (this way it doesn't work):

```
^m & ^t:: Send M and T text{enter}
    Return

^m & ^s:: Send M and S text{enter}
    Return

^t & ^s:: Send T and S text{enter}
    Return
```

I want AHK to take all three sequences like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does one thing and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> does another but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> does a different third action.

There is a similar post to this here: [AutoHotKey key SEQUENCE, not just single-key hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096253/autohotkey-key-sequence-not-just-single-key-hotkey)

Comment: Uh, I don't get it.  Does your code not work for you?  What doesn't it do for you?

Comment: Sorry edited in the explanation.

Comment: This really sounds like hotstrings to me. Have you considered using them instead of hotkeys? Furthermore, I wouldn't recommend using `CTRL + LETTER` hotkeys, since they almost always block some shortcut in many programs. E.g. `^s` is the standard save shortcut in editors; `^t` is the *new tab* shortcut in browsers, and so on.

Comment: Yea i already switched it to alt instead, but I had the same situation so I didn't feel like editing.  Read up hotstrings.  Really kool stuff will use it since it works for one of the things I'm doing.  However, it's not exactly what I wanted. Because I wanted this to work for any action not just text.

Comment: What do you mean by "any action"? Hotstring labels are able to execute any kind of code.

Comment: Oh. Ok.  It's just that the AHK link I found only mentions text replacement. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a fitting solution, you might want to try the workaround which I've been using.

Note: the following does **not** include any hotkey triggers like `^m::`, the problem is being solved with the [hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm)-command and fitting **label** names, which actually look like a hotkey trigger (`^m:`)

```
hotkey, ^m, ^m, On
hotkey, ^t, ^m, On

return

^m_and_^t:  ; will also be called from ^t & ^m
Send M and T text{enter}
triggered = true
return

^m_and_^s:
Send M and S text{enter}
triggered = true
return

^t_and_^s:
Send T and S text {enter}
triggered = true
return

^m:
triggered = false
hotkey, ^t, ^m_and_^t, On
hotkey, ^s, ^m_and_^s, On
loop
{
    getkeystate, isDown, m, P
    if isDown = U
        break
}
hotkey, ^t, ^t, On
hotkey, ^s, ^m_and_^s, Off ; -> ^s will keep its natural function

if triggered = false
{
    Send M text{enter}
}
return

^t:
triggered = false
hotkey, ^s, ^t_and_^s, On
hotkey, ^m, ^m_and_^t, On
loop
{
    getkeystate, isDown, t, P
    if isDown = U
        break
}
hotkey, ^m, ^m, On
hotkey, ^s, ^m_and_^s, Off ; -> ^s will keep its natural function
if triggered = false
{
    Send T text{enter}
}
return
```