# AutoHotkey repeated key sequences, detecting KEYUP and KEYDOWN for modifiers

Tags: unicode, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Similar to what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096253/autohotkey-key-sequence-not-just-single-key-hotkey) covers, I'm trying to bind two sequences of keys.

Ideally I'd like to bind <kbd>Alt DOWN</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>Alt UP</kbd> to an em-dash (—) and <kbd>Alt DOWN</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>Alt UP</kbd> to an en-dash (–).

What I have almost works for em-dashes but not quite:

```
; Em-dash
!-::
Input Key, L1
if Key=-
Input Key, L1
if Key=-
Send {ASC 0151}
return 

; En-dash
;!-::
;Input Key, L1
;if Key=-
;Send {ASC 0150}
;return
```

The em-dash sequence works like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>, instead of what I'm trying to match. I'm not sure how to only test for <kbd>Alt DOWN</kbd> and <kbd>Alt UP</kbd>. The en-dash sequence fails altogether to bind because `!-` has already been bound.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use [hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)? For instance, make typing `---` convert to em-dash, and `--` convert to en-dash.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf I often use `--` in programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this one:

```
dashCount := 0

!-::
    dashCount++
    if(dashCount = 1) {
        SetTimer, WaitForAlt, -1
    }
return

WaitForAlt:
    KeyWait, Alt
    if(dashCount = 2) {
        Send {ASC 0150}
    } else if(dashCount = 3) {
        Send {ASC 0151}
    }
    dashCount := 0
return
```

It seems to do the job well. The code works by counting each time <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> gets pressed. Concurrently, a pseudo-thread is spawned that waits for <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be released and then sends the appropriate `dash`, depending on the counter.

Comment: That works great! Is there API documentation on `SetTimer` or `KeyWait`? Google always returns forum posts from years ago that aren't very helpful.

Comment: @travis I just read that you want to avoid hotstrings since they would be triggered when using the decrement operator. Did you know that you can make context-sensitive hotstrings using `#If` or `#IfWin...`?

Comment: I program with and need the dashes in the same apps, unfortunately.