# Autohotkey: How to implement an exit sequence

Tags: sequence, autohotkey, exit

In order to end my custom keyboard mapping for coding, I have placed the following line at the bottom of my script:

```
Esc::ExitApp
```

However, a single keystroke (especially the Esc) happens too much for other reasons. Therefore, I would prefer a sequence of single keystrokes (not holding down any key) to exit the Autohotkey mapping, such as "Esc and then LCtrl" or "Esc, LCtrl and then again Esc"

I have tried the idea from [AutoHotKey key SEQUENCE, not just single-key hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096253/autohotkey-key-sequence-not-just-single-key-hotkey) :

```
Esc::
Input Key, L1
if Key=LCtrl 
ExitApp  
return
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick: on pressing Esc and then LCtrl, the mapping doesn't stop. (Also, if I press Esc and then another key (not LCtrl) that next keystroke is ignored, something I would preferably not have.

Comment: Why didn't the suggestions in the linked question do the trick? Please post your code and specify what didn't work.

Comment: I have added the specific code that I have tried.

Comment: Have a look at the [Input docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm). In order to catch non-character keys, you can define `EndKeys`. Anyway, why don't you just use a native hotkey like `^ESC` or `^+ESC`? It's just as safe when it comes to accidental triggering of your routine and will save you lots of scripting trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1a:**

```
LCtrl & Esc::
ExitApp
return
```

You can add this code anywhere in your script. Press <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> and after <kbd>Esc</kbd> for script to exit.

**Version 1b:**

```
Esc & LCtrl::
ExitApp
return
```

You can add this code anywhere in your script. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and after <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> for script to exit.

You can add both **Version 1a** and **Version 1b**. In that case, when you press <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> and after <kbd>Esc</kbd> *OR* <kbd>Esc</kbd> and after <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> script will exit.

**Version 2** (it uses different method, use it if for some reason you don't like **Version 1a** or/and **Version 1b**)**:**

```
Loop
{
    a := GetKeyState("Esc")
    if (a=1)
    {
        b := GetKeyState("LCtrl")

        if (b=1)
        {
            ExitApp
        }

    }
}
```

That code should be launch after your other code will remap all keys you need. Press <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> and after <kbd>Esc</kbd> *OR* <kbd>Esc</kbd> and after <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> for script to exit.

**EDIT:**

**Version 3**:

```
Loop
{
    a := GetKeyState("Esc")
    if (a=1)
    {
        Loop,60 ;number of 50 milliseconds script will wait to CTRL press. Example 60 means 60*50=3000, so script will wait 3000 milliseconds (1sec=1000 milliseconds) for CTRL press. After that time you have to press Esc again.
        {
            b := GetKeyState("LCtrl")

            if (b=1)
            {
                ExitApp
            }
            Sleep, 50
        }

    }
}
```

That code should be launch after your other code will remap all keys you need. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> (now you can release <kbd>Esc</kbd> ) and within 3000 milliseconds (1sec=1000 milliseconds) press <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>. After that time you have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> again for script to exit. If you want to modify time after which you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> again read the comment in the code.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Did you know that `return` after `ExitApp` is unreachable code? Also, I don't think this exactly matches OP's requirements, since in your  examples, the keys have to be pressed simultaneously. In contrast, I believe OP wants to be able to exit by typing a combination like `CTRL`, `ESC`, `CTRL` one after another.

Comment: @MCL Yes, you are right about `return` after `ExitApp`. I did not paid attention to that, I just always writing `return` at the end of hotkey.

Comment: @MCL OP said: `Therefore, I would prefer a sequence of single keystrokes (not holding down any key) to exit the Autohotkey mapping, such as "Esc and then LCtrl" or "Esc, LCtrl and then again Esc"`. So Understand that "Esc and then LCtrl" is ok for him.

Comment: @MCL Added also version 3.

Comment: @T_at'Ghent Added also version 3.

Comment: A permanent loop in order to catch a key sequence sounds rather rash. Also, after `ESC` was pressed, the script will "wait" indefinitely until `LCtrl` is pressed and then exit, without taking the time between key pressed into consideration. In other words, if you press `ESC` and 10 minutes later `LCtrl`, the script will exit anyway, which can't be what you want.

Comment: @MCL Please check version 3 again. I corrected version 3. I though previous version was exactly what OP asked for but newer version 3 is more logically right and I think he will like it more then he asked for.