# Two-key combinations with modifier keys

Tags: autohotkey

I can do plain two-key combinations, eg `F & G::`

but how to do so with modifier keys, say
holding *alt-win-F (3 keys pressed)* then *G* (now 4 keys pressed)?

Both `!#F & G::` and `!#F & !#G` fail.

Comment: Here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096253/autohotkey-key-sequence-not-just-single-key-hotkey

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a physical limitation with some keyboards. Anyway, try something like :

```
!#F::
Input key, I L1
IfEqual key,g
MsgBox Success!
Return
```

See the following for more information:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/5408-multiple-letter-hotkeys/